# Import serial to Python

Tags: python, arduino-uno

I do have a problem which many people faced already, but after searching through different solutions for hours, I still haven't solved my problem.
For a project, I need Phyton to read my Data from my arduino-uno. Therefore I need the import serial (or import pyserial, I tried both) this doesn't work. I tried installing the library (not really sure where to store it than) but that didn't help either. I also tried using "pip install pyserial" in the console, but that didn't work as well.

Whatever i do i allwas get this error:

> > > pip install pyserial
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           pip install pyserial
> > >                     ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I reinstalled Python now as 2.7 and deleted everything Python related. But when i put in pip install pyserial i still geht the same Error

Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with the commands you tried, as well as their stacktrace?

Comment: I tried: import serial; import pyserial; pip install serial; pip install pyserial. I downloaded the library from https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/ and followed the instructions. But i don't really know where to put the file. I put it to the other libraies in the phgs folder. If i try to import any other library it does work however

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your question, not in a comment. It's also not complete: please add what happened next. ("Nothing but a blinking cursor", "My computer started to smoke", "A computer voice said 'I'm sorry Dave but I cannot let you do that'", etc.)

Comment: When you run `which pip` (Linux) or `where pip` (Windows) in the command line, what does it show? Make sure it's installing to the right python

Comment: where pip also gives me: invalid syntax

Comment: Where are you entering `pip install pyserial` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed `pyserial` as you stated in the comments using the PyPI command `pip install pyserial` then you should use

```
import serial
```

and not `import pyserial` as it is shown in the [documentation here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html)

---

If this doesn't work, either there was a problem when installing the library, or you may not be using the same Python environment as the one you think you are (as you did not give details on how you run the script it's hard to tell).

Comment: I still get the same errormessage

  File "<ipython-input-2-130efcbcc726>", line 1, in <module>
    import serial

ImportError: No module named serial; 
Seems to be a problem with the file but i don't know how to solve it. Where do i need to put the file after downloading it?

Comment: I see there is an `ipython` here, I am not sure you are using the same python environment here and where you installed pyserial, you should post the commands you type and the files you are running.

Comment: I used Spyder (Python 2.7) and Python with the Jupyter Notebook, sorry i sound quite stupid, i'm comming of a Mathematica Project and am really confused right now

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!
Seems like my computer doesn't like python.

Thanks for your help